# Programação Modular

Tags: c#

Algo bastante corriqueiro no desenvolvimento de sistemas para negócios e como satisfazermos diversos requisitos, sendo esses requisitos muitas vezes não usados por determinados clientes, como por exemplo, quando uma empresa que atua no ramo de vendas não necessitaria do módulo de prestação de serviço que é usado por empresas prestadoras de serviços. Surgindo assim a necessidade do desenvolvimento de software modular para satisfazer tais requisitos

- A aplicação é comercializada por módulos – o cliente pode comprar o módulo de vendas, mas não o de controle industrial.
- A aplicação pode ser desenvolvida por times separados – cada time desenvolve um módulo independente.
- Os módulos só são carregados quando o usuário tem acesso a ele.
- A aplicação não precisa ser distribuída por inteiro quando um módulo é alterado
- Podemos criar novos módulos e adicioná-los ao sistema sem que seja necessário alterar os outros módulos

Com um pouco de leitura sobre o assunto, podemos logo chegar ao Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)

> A Managed Extensibility Framework ou MEF é uma biblioteca para criar aplicativos leves e extensíveis. Ele permite que os desenvolvedores de aplicativos descubram e usem extensões sem nenhuma configuração necessária. Isso também permite aos desenvolvedores de extensão encapsular o código facilmente e evitar dependências rígidas frágeis. A MEF não só permite que extensões sejam reutilizadas em aplicativos, mas também entre aplicativos.

Minha duvida fica em torno de usar ou não MEF?

Existe outras alternativas?

OBS: Exemplos são sempre bem vindos.

Comment: Minha duvida é com relação se é aplicável desenvolver um sistema modular usando MEF ou outros frameworks.

Comment: Outra questão que me lembrei seria com relação ao desempenho de usar MEF ou outro framework

Comment: SOA seria para programação orientada a serviços, correto? meu objetivo não seria esse e sim criar uma aplicação plugável onde em um mesmo sistema ele possa ter módulos diferentes, não precisando ser distribuído.

Comment: econtrei acidentalmente este curso sobre MEF na pluralsight, talvez te interesse: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mef

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pablo, eu trabalho com isso há muito tempo já usando C# em um sistema interdependente! Acho que mesmo sendo interdependente, conseguimos de uma maneira geral modularizar o sistema.

Temos uma metodologia própria para criar nossas especializações por módulos, não exatamente a como mostrado nos artigos da [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) sobre o assunto.

Nosso sistema começou todo modular, mas com o tempo ele passou (naturalmente) a ser totalmente integrado. Temos muitos clientes que ainda compram somente alguns módulos. Mas aí surge uma necessidade intrínseca: **integrações**!

## Exemplo: Compra de módulos onde você é um especialista

Veja um caso: Você é um especialista em controle de estoques e logística. Seu sistema é incrível nesses módulos, mas é péssimo em fazer apresentações em HML5 incríveis com milhões de fotografias atualizadas a toda semana.

Se um cliente procurar você por ser especialista nesse assunto, provavelmente você precisará de várias integrações: Notas fiscais de entrada para saber o que está entrando no estoque (compras e retorno de estoque), um cadastro de materiais atualizado, uma integração para pedidos e reservas de estoque e outra ainda para notas fiscais de saída para dar baixa no estoque. Talvez ainda uma outra integração para notificação de materiais quebrados.

## Vendas modulares

Hoje em dia já estamos mais maduros com relação à vendas de módulos em separados. Embora temos módulos e especializações (exemplo, vendemos o módulo de faturamento. Mas no Brasil faturamos de um jeito, no Chile de outro, etc), nós também possuímos um mecanismo sólido de integrações para todos os módulos.

Naturalmente, existe uma interdependência entre todos os módulos. Mesmo que o cliente queira comprar somente um módulo ou outro, é preciso mapear as interdependências e ter certeza que ele adquira um produto sólido.

## Mecanismo modular especializado

A maneira como fazemos hoje é a seguinte: Nossos módulos são carregados um a um por interfaces comuns distribuídas no sistema. Existe uma `Factory` dessas interfaces que verifica, a cada vez que é chamado, se o módulo já foi carregado ou não, se não estiver ele carrega (cada módulo nosso está em uma DLL específica por módulo e por especialização, para fácil visualização).

Usamos muito o *reflection* para esses casos. Vale a pena dar uma estudada. Nós temos um *DLL* comum que define o que é um objeto do tipo `Modulo` e interfaces comuns que este objeto deve implementar. Depois estes objetos podem ser instanciados e usados quando necessário.

Você pode chamar em qualquer ponto do sistema, por exemplo, o modulo de faturamento para faturar um pedido, exemplo `ModuloFaturamento.FaturarPedido(codigoPedido);`. Se o cliente possuí o módulo, o pedido é realmente faturado. Senão, uma *stub* pode ser implementada para não fazer nada ou uma integração pode ser feita com uma requisição para um sistema externo (exemplo: SAP).

## Resumo

Acredito que a modularização é bem viável, mas existe um gasto considerável em integrações quando o cliente não deseja todos os módulos. Tente se especializar nos módulos em que seus clientes atuais dão maior importância. Entenda tudo dele e se torne referência. Os outros começarão a vir com mais naturalidade caso necessário.

Comment: Muito bom seu conteúdo, é exatamente onde quero chegar, só estou procurando frameworks que apoiam no desenvolvimento modular. Já fiz pequenos exemplos com o MEF e até que foram satisfatórios, mas antes de decidir usar ele, queria mais opiniões de quem já trabalha com assunto.

Comment: O seu exemplo FaturarPedido é bem corriqueiro de acontecer, pois nem todos usam o financeiro, as vezes só precisam controlar estoque e emitir NFe, logo não implementaria o financeiro nesse caso